# Equivalence proof diagonalization

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonal-matrices

I would like to check if the last equivalence of the following equivalence chain is actually true:

\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\sum_i \left(a_1 s_i^4 + a_2 s_i^2 s_{i+1}^2\right) &= \, s^T \text{diag}(s)\,\, A\,\, \text{diag}(s) \,\, s 
\\ & =  s^T \text{diag}(s)\,\, M \,\, D \,\, M^T \,\, \text{diag}(s) \,\, s  
\\&= z^T \,\, M^T \,\text{diag}(s)\,\, M \,\, D \,\,M^T \,\text{diag}(s) \,\,M\,\,z  \\& \overset{?}{=}  \,\, z^T\,\text{diag}(z)\,\,D\,\text{diag}(z)\,\,z = \sum_i \Lambda_i z_i^4   
\end{aligned}
\end{equation} 
Where $M$ is the orthogonal matrix that transform the matrix $A$ into its diagonal matrix $D=\text{diag}(\Lambda_1,\Lambda_2,...,\Lambda_n)$ and $z=M^T s$.

Comment: The final equivalence seems to rest on the equation $M^T\operatorname{diag}(s)M = \operatorname{diag}(z)$.  Let $e_i$ denote the $i$th standard basis vector (the $i$th column of the identity matrix if you prefer). We can compute the $i,j$ entry of this product as
$$
(M^T\operatorname{diag}(s)M)_{i,j} = e_i^T(M^T\operatorname{diag}(s)M)e_j= 
(e_i^TM^T) \operatorname{diag}(s) (M e_j)\\
= (Me_i)^T\operatorname{diag}(s)(M e_j)
$$

Comment: In order for $M^T\operatorname{diag}(s)M$ to be diagonal, we would need to have $(Me_i)^T\operatorname{diag}(s)(M e_j) = 0$ whenever $i \neq j$.  Since all we know about $Me_i$ and $Me_j$ is that they are mutually orthogonal, I see no reason to believe that this should generally be the case.

Comment: Maybe it can be used the fact that $M$ is the matrix that diagonalize $A$ (which is cyclical and has a very peculiar form)?